# Windowed Feature Extraction in R for a Matlab User

Tags: r, matlab

I started to program in R (coming from Matlab) and I just wondered if there is a built-in R function similar to the buffer.m in Matlab 
see:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/buffer.html

I currently implemented it on my own, still a built in function might be useful/faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab's `buffer` command can be expressed using `rollapply` from zoo.  The following one liner gives the same result as `buffer(x, n, p)` and seems to work for non-negative p:

```
> library(zoo)
> x <- 1:30
> n <- 7
> p <- 3
> unname(t(rollapply(zoo(c(rep(0, p), x, rep(0, n-p))),  n, by = n-p, c)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0    2    6   10   14   18   22   26
[2,]    0    3    7   11   15   19   23   27
[3,]    0    4    8   12   16   20   24   28
[4,]    1    5    9   13   17   21   25   29
[5,]    2    6   10   14   18   22   26   30
[6,]    3    7   11   15   19   23   27    0
[7,]    4    8   12   16   20   24   28    0
```

In the development version of zoo this can be shortened slightly to:

```
t(rollapply(c(rep(0, p), x, rep(0, n-p)),  n, by = n-p, c))
```

EDIT:

Note that what was the development version of zoo when the question was first answered has become the production version of zoo on CRAN so the shorter second version of the code now works.

Answer (score 2):

The `embed` function can help here. Here for example is the `buffer(x,n,p)` for `p > 0`. I will leave the other variants as an exercise.

```
buffer <- function(x,n,p) {
  L <- length(x)
  nC <- ceiling( L /(n-p) )  
  xPad <- c(rep(0,p), x, rep(0, nC * (n - p) - L))
  t(embed( xPad, dim=n)[seq(1, length(xPad) - n + 1, by=n-p), n:1])
}



> buffer(1:30,7,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0    2    6   10   14   18   22   26
[2,]    0    3    7   11   15   19   23   27
[3,]    0    4    8   12   16   20   24   28
[4,]    1    5    9   13   17   21   25   29
[5,]    2    6   10   14   18   22   26   30
[6,]    3    7   11   15   19   23   27    0
[7,]    4    8   12   16   20   24   28    0
```

Comment: I don't think there is a `ceil` function in default R, are you relying on a local or another package version? The base package function is `ceiling`.

Comment: you're right, I had the `Hmisc` package loaded, and it was picking up `ceil` from there. I changed it to use `ceiling`.